# Wordpress Pagination showing same posts on all pages

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, pagination

On this page [here](http://fusion.fusionconstruction.co.uk/latest-news/), I'm using the following php code to show the posts:

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts($args);
if( have_posts() ) :?>

<?php twentyeleven_content_nav( 'nav-above' );?>
<?php
$withThumb = 5; 
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
if ($withThumb-- > 0) { ?>
    <div class="post-thumb-title">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(632,305));?></a>
        <p class="thumb-title2"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
        <p class="news-date"><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></p>
        <div id="post-excerpt">
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } else { ?>
    <div class="post-title">
        <p class="thumb-title2">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </p>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php twentyeleven_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>
```

The issue is that if you click on "[Older Posts](http://fusion.fusionconstruction.co.uk/latest-news/page/2/)", it shows the same posts and not the older ones.

It does the same when you open the 3rd page, 4th page and so on.

How do I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the page number to the arguments of the `query_posts()` call.

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args['paged'] = $paged;
query_posts($args);
```

See the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#Adding_the_.22paged.22_parameter_to_a_query).

**Note:** If you've already defined `$args` and as a string not an array, you'll want to concatenate `&paged=page_number_here`, instead of adding a new key-value pair.